# php pdo and html entity decode

Tags: php, pdo

The data was inserted into the database after being escaped as follows:

```
$caller=htmlentities($formVarsI['caller'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

Some of the $caller's have single quotes e.g. O'Connor and these then look like O`&#039;`Connor in the database.

I am now trying to extract the data using a REST api and below is my php:

```
$sql = "SELECT caller FROM tbl_calls ";
try {
    $db = getConnection();
    $stmt = $db->query($sql);  
    $calls= $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $db = null;
    echo json_encode($calls);
    }
```

My question is how to html_entity_decode on $caller so as to remove the

```
&#039;
```

for each caller where it applies.  Note there are approx. 10,000 entries in the db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should specify the quotes parameter.

```
html_entity_decode('O&#039;Connor', ENT_QUOTES);
// output: O'Connor
```

By default it's `ENT_COMPACT` and it just convert double quotes, not single.

Comment: thanks, but how do I incorporate the html_entity_decode before it returns the json encoded result?

Comment: @Joe: You would use `html_entity_decode()` in a loop, like this: `foreach ($calls as &$call) { $call->caller = html_entity_decode($call->caller, ENT_QUOTES); } unset($call);`

Answer (score 6):

The solution, of course, is to **stop using `htmlentities()` to escape data going into a database.**

The `htmlentities()` function is for escaping data to be injected into an HTML document context.  Not a database.

Comment: thanks.  I should have pointed out that it is a legacy database, and I am accessing it on a read only basis so therefore cannot change the htmlentities() aspect.

Comment: Ah, okay.  In that case, most (if not all) RDBMSs have no HTML entity decoding abilities, because they aren't concerned with HTML.  You would have to post-process the database results using `html_entity_decode()` in the way that @Entropy answered.